# how to write a c/c++ variable to shell script?

Tags: c++, shell

I want to send the C/C++ variable into my shell script, but tried many ways on the Internet, seems not working, could you help me with my code?
C++ code:

```
void test::addroute(){
string test1=ip_address;
}
```

my shell script:

```
#!bin/sh
ip rule add from $test1 lookup $eth0_table
```

how to send the test1 to here?

Comment: It very much depends on your OS and on the particular use case (why do you need that? how many variables are passed? What kind of variables do you need?)

Comment: You can run `ip` from your C code directly. e.g. `system("ip rule add...");`

Answer (score 0):

You can print the variable content on `stdout` and include it with using subcall `$()`.

So if you program will be called `test`. Just call it like

```
ip rule add from $(test) lookup ...
```

If you need more complex output, make it a csv-like format and use it like this:

```
output="$(test)"
first="$(echo ${output}|cut -d ';' -f 1 )"
second="$(echo ${output}|cut -d ';' -f 2 )"
ip rule add from "${first}" lookup "${second}"
```

Don't know if changing variables directly would make a bit of chaos.